# I want to get the userid of user on discord whose message starts with >

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('>'):
        user = client.get_user(user_id)
        print(user)
```

The error shows `user_id` isn't a defined variable.
I have already imported discord; what else needs to be imported or installed?

Comment: The variable  `user_id` needs to be defined somewhere. Since it's likely that a message has a user associated with it I would start looking at the `message` object and see if the user id can be found as a property or returned from a method. Next look at the documentation for the `@client.event` decorator which may be also able to define variables within your method's scope that could contain relevant context.

Comment: thanks, I will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `message.author.id`. Try this out:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('>'):
        user_id = message.author.id
        user = await client.fetch_user(int(user_id))
        print(user)
```

Comment: @Shivalee ok, try `user = await client.fetch_user(int(user_id))` instead of `user = client.get_user(int(user_id))`

Comment: @Shivalee also, make sure to click the accept button below the downvote button next to my post if this helped you out!

Comment: I tried printing user_id and I got the correct output.... so it serves my purpose...thank you :)